# matlab K-means using datevec

Tags: matlab, k-means

I am new to matlab and machine learning. I have some data over time and I want to use k-means. The time is in datevec format.
Is it possible to perform kmeans to find the means using datevec format as my training data?

Comment: Why not use your dates in the `datenum` format? The conversion is trivial (`datenums = datenum(datevecs)`) and I'd guess the clustering should be faster as well...

Comment: @sebastian it is required to use datevec...yes it should be simpler to use datenum but I cannot..

Comment: That means you want to cluster your dates according to year, month, day, etc.? It would be good if you would explain in more detail how your data look like (only dates?) and what you are trying to achieve using the k-means.